# Email alert for Google Scholar's recommended articles

Tags: google-scholar, productivity

I really like Google Scholar's list of "recommended articles". I usually find  useful references there related to my work that I did not know about.

But I rarely log into Google Scholar to check them out and I would like a more convenient way of being informed about new items in that list (i.e., one that would flow more easily in my daily routine).

I do check my emails every day, so an email alert would be best.

- Is there any way to receive an email alert about new items in my "recommended articles" list?
- If not, does Google Scholar has a process for "feature requests" where I could ask about implementing this?

Comment: https://scholar.google.fr/intl/fr/scholar/help.html#alerts

Comment: Please keep discussion friendly and civil.